# Any difference between pip installed with python32bit and pip installed with python64bit?

Tags: python, pip

`python_32 get-pip.py` vs `python_64 get-pip.py`

Any difference in `pip` installed?

For example I installed `Django` with pip_32.

Can I use `Django` with `python_64`.

I check it by importing and a importing has no problem.

However, I am not sure that if there is any potential risk.

Comment: What operating system? Usually PyPI packages installed with a 32bit pip are not available on 64bit Python and vice versa.

Comment: It will depend on how your system is setup, for example if you have 32-bit python as well.  Avoid mixing 32 and 64 bit if you possibly can, this site is littered with posts where people try to do that and fall down holes.